# Using a Knowledge Distillation model to run predictions and check classification metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am running the Keras example on knowledge distillation from the [keras example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/) and my question is: The resulting compressed model that I can use to do predictions is the distiller or the student model? And in such case, how do I add back the softmax classification layer and run predictions using the resulting model?

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    import numpy as np
    
    batch_size = 64
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255.0
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 28, 28, 1))

    x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255.0
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
    teacher = keras.Sequential(
        [
            keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding="same"),
            layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(10),
        ],
        name="teacher",
    )
    
    # Create the student
    student = keras.Sequential(
        [
            keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding="same"),
            layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(10),
        ],
        name="student",
    )

    teacher.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )
    
        teacher.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
        teacher.evaluate(x_test, y_test)



distiller = Distiller(student=student, teacher=teacher)
distiller.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    student_loss_fn=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    distillation_loss_fn=keras.losses.KLDivergence(),
    alpha=0.1,
    temperature=10,
)

# Distill teacher to student
distiller.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

# Evaluate student on test dataset
distiller.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Despite being able to run the example, I don't think these informations are clear to me, I would like to test the model on unseen data, therefore I was wondering, how do I build a model from Knowledge Distillation and perform predictions and check its classification report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "compressed" model is the student model.  The `Distiller` is just the wrapper for training the student to try and mimic the teacher, as opposed to training the student to try and estimate the ground-truth labels.
The page you linked has a section comparing the distillation results to the equivalent light-weight student architecture with "from scratch" training against actual labels, so predictions are rather straight-forward from the tutorial.
Note that the teacher and student both only have a `dense` layer at their end, and the training therefor assumes that the loss should be calculated by viewing the model outputs as `logits`.  So both the teacher and the student outputs just need a simple `tf.nn.softmax` for getting the standard categorical score.
Don't forget to recalibrate the softmax temperature if necessary.

Comment: The predictions are done using a separate student model, I was wondering how should the model be rebuilt after the distillation to do the predictions, will it have the generalization required on the data?

Comment: Whether or not it will generalize well or not is a matter of how well your teacher did, the nature of the data, the nature of the split, and lots more.

Comment: No need to rebuild. Just use the trained student on your test data, and add a softmax activation as I mentioned. That's all.